# Transformations in spark streaming taking more time even though there are 0 messages

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have serious performance issue with spark streaming. For 10 seconds batch interval, program is taking around 2 mins. I tried to debug without 0 messages from kafka topic. Most of the transformations are taking more than 30 seconds time even though there are no messages to consume/process. The below command is taking around 40 seconds even though there are no messages in decodeMessagesDF.

```
val enrichedDF: DataFrame = decodeMessagesDF.join(broadcast(customer), (decodeMessagesDF( "rowkey") === customer("rowkey")) && (customer("mkt_opto_flag") === "N") && (customer("ads_opto_flag") === "N"))
```

Also the below code for publishing is also taking around 30 seconds for 0 messages to publish

```
  message.foreachPartition{ part =>
  val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
  part.foreach{ msg =>
    val message = new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, msg._1, msg._2)
    producer.send(message)
  }
  producer.close()
```

}

Please let me know if there is anything wrong in the code. Thanks

Comment: Do you find any clues in the logs? AFAIK, the codes look good.

Comment: No, I couldnt find anything in the logs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast is expensive if 'customer' has large number of data.And maybe you should put broadcast(customer) out of join operation like this:

```
    val consumerBroadcast = sc.broadcast(customer)
    val enrichedDF: DataFrame = decodeMessagesDF.join(broadcast(consumerBroadcast), (decodeMessagesDF( "rowkey") === customer("rowkey")) && (customer("mkt_opto_flag") === "N") && (customer("ads_opto_flag") === "N"))
```

This code will broadcast customer only once.But your code will broadcast consumer every batch.